# PHP URL is working on broswer but when i tried to run it from my android application InputStream is null

Tags: java, php, android

I new to android and want to call web service written in PHP from android application; but I am getting `InputStream` as null. But when I tried to run same URL from browser it is showing the output.
My php file: (userlogin.php)

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("IP Address of server","Any","","user");

if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
{
   echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$username = $_GET['username'];
$password = $_GET['password'];

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM userLogin where username = '$username' and password = '$password'");


$n_filas = mysqli_num_rows ($result);

$array = array();
    for ($i=0; $i<$n_filas; $i++)
    {
        $fila = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    $array[$i]['username'] = utf8_encode($fila['username']);
        $array[$i]['password'] = utf8_encode($fila['password']);
    }
    $result= json_encode($array);
    echo $result;


mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

and my JSON parser :

```
public JSONArray makeHttpRequest(String url, ArrayList<String> params) {

        try
        {
            URL url1 = new URL("http://IP ADDRESS OF SERVER/userlogin.php?username="+params.get(0)+"&password="+params.get(1));
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url1.openConnection();
            urlConnection.connect();
            is = urlConnection.getInputStream();

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        try {
            Log.d("String is",is.toString());
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();

            Log.d("String ===",json);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try
        {
            Log.d("In JSON Object try ", "yes");
            jObj = new JSONArray(json);
            Log.d("String Json ===",jObj.toString());
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;
        }
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thank You.

Comment: Which Server Tool You Are Using like PHPMyAdmin Or Apache Tomcat?

Comment: I am using PHPMyAdmin

Comment: You never use the `url` `String` passed to this method, are you sure you're trying to connect to the correct URL ?

Comment: Yes m sure that I am trying to connect the correct URL.

Comment: Are you able to access http://IP ADDRESS OF SERVER/userlogin.php via devices's browser ?

Comment: I am getting these types of error:

01-18 15:45:34.699 7143-7344/? E/Buffer Error: Error converting result java.lang.NullPointerException: lock == null
01-18 15:45:34.699 7143-7344/? E/JSON Parser: Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of 
01-18 15:45:34.750 295-653/? E/audio_a2dp_hw: adev_set_parameters: ERROR: set param called even when stream out is null

Comment: First off: **Don't** pass credentials via an unencrypted HTTP request. Either encrypt that or abandon authentication altogether. But back to your question: I see a `is = urlConnection.getInputStream()` in the upper part of your code. And then there is a `new InputStreamReader(is)` a few lines further down. Are they suppose to refer to the same thing? If so, then... well you need to rewrite this.

Comment: @morido Please can u explain what exactly I have to do..

Comment: @joy d yes I am able to access IP ADDRESS OF SERVER/uerlogin.php via device's browser.

Comment: have you given internet permission?

Comment: BTW: Your PHP is prone to [SQL injections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) since you do not sanitize the username / password. **Don't** ever do that for production code.

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me:

```
public static void retrieveData() {

    try {
        // the following line is BAD - do not supply username + password via such an insecure connection!       
        URL url1 = new URL("http://IP ADDRESS OF SERVER/userlogin.php?username="+params.get(0)+"&password="+params.get(1));

        URLConnection urlConnection = url1.openConnection();
        // you may want to adjust the timeout here, like so:
        // urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(timeout);
        urlConnection.connect();
        try (InputStream is = urlConnection.getInputStream()) {
            processData(is);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // do something smart
        }
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // do something smart
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // do something smart
    } 

}

private static void processData(InputStream is) {
    try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is))) {       
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }

    // rest of your processing logic

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // do something smart
    } 
}
```

These methods do not necessarily have to be *static* and you may of course amend their signature (parameters, return value) to suit your needs.

Comment: @ASK Then please accept the answer so the question can be archived.